# Lxml - how to wrap all occurences of specific text in a tag

Tags: html, parsing, lxml

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
      Some foo text foo
      <p> text inside paragraph foo and also foo and <b> nested foo</b> and foo </p>
      foo is also here and can occur many times foo foo
      <p> here <a>foo</a> already appears inside a link so it is not changed</p>
      foo, yeah!
</div>
```

I need to wrap all occurrences of 'foo' in a clickable link (`<a>` element), except the occurences that are already inside `<a>`, so the expected output is:

```
<div>
      Some <a>foo</a> text <a>foo</a>
      <p> text inside paragraph <a>foo</a> and also <a>foo</a> and <b> nested <a>foo</a></b> and <a>foo</a> </p>
      <a>foo</a> is also here and can occur many times <a>foo</a> <a>foo</a>
      <p> here <a> foo </a> appears inside a link so it is not changed</p>
      <a>foo</a>, yeah!
    </div>
```

Is there an easy way of doing that with lxml? Raw substring replace made more sense to me initially but there's this requirement that some occurrences must not be changed if they're inside specific elements of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

OK, BeautifulSoup seems way better than raw lxml for that purpose

This code works pretty well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = """<div>
      Some foo text foo
      <p> text inside paragraph foo and also foo and <b> nested foo</b> and foo </p>
      foo is also here and can occur many times foo foo
      <p> here <a>foo</a> already appears inside a link so it is not changed</p>
      foo, yeah!
</div>"""

s = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
print(s)

for text_node in list(s.strings):
      if not text_node.parent.name=='a':
            text_node.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(text_node.string.replace('foo', '<a>foo</a>'), 'html.parser'))

print(s)
```

Edit: it is important to use html.parser. Passing "lxml" when constructing a replacment HTML fragment is not working well (wraps the HTML fragment in html tag)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you to where I think you're going:

```
x_list = x.split(' ')
for word in range (len(x_list)):
    if 'foo' in x_list[word]:
       if x_list[word] != '<a>foo</a>':
               x_list[word]='<a>foo</a>'
new_x = ' '.join(x_list)
print(new_x.strip('\n'))
```

Output:

```
<div>
  Some <a>foo</a> text <a>foo</a>      <p> text inside paragraph <a>foo</a> and also <a>foo</a> and <b> nested <a>foo</a> and <a>foo</a> </p>
  <a>foo</a> is also here and can occur many times <a>foo</a> <a>foo</a>      <p> here <a>foo</a> already appears inside a link so it is not changed</p>
  <a>foo</a> yeah!
```

Comment: That would work but my question wasn't precise enough. I can't assume that foo string will always be directly wrapped in <a>, besides even with your code it won't work if there are some whitespaces eg '<a> foo    </a>'. Therefore my assumption was that the document string needs to be HTML parsed in order to detect that kind of ocurrences.

Comment: Your second point (about the whitespaces) can be easily addressed, but before I do that, can you clarify your first point - what do you mean by "can't assume that foo string will always be directly wrapped in <a>"? Can you give an example of a string like that which needs to be left untouched?